# What is a recommended Storm distribution?

Tags: bigdata, apache-storm

I want to try install [Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_%28event_processor%29).

Does Storm have distributions like [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) (cloudera, mapr, etc.)?
Or should I install all by myself (ZEROMQ, GZMQ, etc.)

What about versions? Where can I find the versions to use?
I see that Storm has 0.8.1. ZeroMq is already at version 3.2.2.

Comment: Note that you never "install" ZeroMQ per se; you simply include it into you application, like any other dll you create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Storm-starter project](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter) on GitHub is a good place to start. You can easily deploy and run local topologies (entirely on your own machine). It is useful for getting your first topology up and running.

If you want to deploy Storm to [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) you should take a look at the [Storm-deploy](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy) project. This will take care of the installation of the correct dependencies on AWS (Zookeeper, etc.).

There's a steep enough learning curve, but if you work through the online documentation you should be able to get the sample topology deployed to AWS pretty quickly.

The [Storm wiki](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki) is the primary source of Storm documentation.